# Use of Services in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, benchmarking, angular-services

I online read that you should a use Service for getting data instead of simply putting the code in the controller, in order to keep Controllers thin.

Here's my Controller, which fetches a list of employees:

```
angular.module("app").controller("MyController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/api/getempl").then(function (response) {
        if (response.status == 200) {
            $scope.empData = response.data.data;
        } else {
            console.log('400');
        }
    });
});
```

Then I tried the _Service approach in hope for improved performance

```
angular.module("app").factory("testService", function ($http, $location) {
    return {
        getData: function () {
            var promise = $http.get("/api/getempl").then(function (response) {
                return response.data.data;
            });
            return promise;
        }
    };
});
```

Now when I injected the Service like as shown up, and tested it in firebug under net tab, there's no improvement in page load time but it rather increased instead.

What am I doing wrong in the code, or what concept am I missing with the usage of Services in AngularJS?

```
angular.module("app").controller("MyController", function ($scope, $http, testService) {
    testService.getData().then(function (response) {
        $scope.empData = response;
    });
});
```

Comment: It's not about performance, it's about separating concerns and keeping code clean.

Comment: @dfsq Okkk..got it ..just one more thing ..I am confused whether to use `Service` or `Resource` for my api hits for better performance ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of services is recommended not for performance but for separation of concerns and code cleanliness. Having said that, if your controller has only a single $http call, then no point creating a service just for the sake of having a service.

Comment: Thx for the answer, whether to use Service or Resource for my api hits for better performance ?

Comment: Obeying the single responsibility principal makes your classes very testable, in this case having a service with sensible method names means you can write a test saying "When this happens on the controller it calls 'GetData' on the service"

Comment: Do you mean, whether to use $http or $resource? In any case the recommendation is to encapsulate $http or $resource calls in services.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding performance there's no real difference. The Controller-Service approach is meant to separate responsibilities (GUI behavior in Controller, state and business logic in services).

This is because Services in AngularJS are global singletons (within a module). Controllers are instanced every time they are needed.

The Service approach makes sure your Controllers don't depend on $scope too much and on other Controllers, as most of the logic should be moved to your Services. This way logic can also be reused across Controllers.